# Django, filter distinct foreign keys where one result equals a value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating a tv website where there's 'people' and 'tvpeople' tables, the first for the actor info and the second for info about an appearance in a show they make.

There can be multiple occurrences of the same actor in a show so multiples of tvpeople. Id like to show a summary of tvpeople that have the field value 'in_summary'=true

Currently I have:

```
cast_summary = tvpeople.filter(in_summary=True)
```

However the output of this brings multiples of the same tvpeople e.g

```
John Doe
John Doe
John Doe
```

Id like to not collect more than one of the same peson based on the value of 'tvpeople.people.name' being distinct.

The following results in an error about the choice being invalid:

```
cast_summary = tvpeople.filter(in_summary=True).distinct('people.name')
```

Any ideas how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, [traversing relationship is done using `__`, not `.`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

Assuming that `tvpeople` has a `people` attribute, then the query would be:

```
t_summary = tvpeople.filter(in_summary=True).distinct('people__name')
```

Posting the relevant code from your models in the question would help, though.

Comment: that gives the exception "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" (im using mysql)

Comment: FYI: people is a foreign key .name is in the people table

Comment: @damnyouiredmail You might want to have a look at this django ticket (or just use Postgres ;) ): https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17974 Using `values_list` should work, but might not be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
t_people = tvpeople.filter(in_summary=True).values('name').distinct()
```

will give you the unique values of names of people in the show (assuming your column it titled 'name').  If you want people objects, you can then do:

```
people = people.filter(name__in=t_people).distinct()
```

Assuming your database isn't giant, this should work for what you need.